# R how to bind character vector with matrix numbers

Tags: r, matrix, character

I have a 3*4 matrix (called S1), let's say:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 1 1
```

and I have a character vector called 'frequency':

```
CX
XU
UK
```

The idea is to bind them such as

```
CX 1 2 3 4
XU 5 6 7 8
UK 9 1 1 1
```

I have tried using cbind as

> result = cbind(frequency, S1)

But the result that R produces is

```
"CX" "1"  "2" "3" "4" 
"XU" "5"  "6" "7" "8"
"UK" "9"  "1" "1" "1"
```

Any idea how to get rid of the parenthesis?

Comment: You can both add the character vector as the `rownames` of the matrix, or use a `data.frame` that lets you combine columns of different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S1` is matrix and matrix can hold data of only one type. Since `frequency` is a character vector it coerces `S1` values to character as well.

Turn `S1` to dataframe

```
cbind(frequency, data.frame(S1))
```

OR

```
cbind.data.frame(frequency, S1)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Generate data

```
frequency <- c("CU", "XU", "UK")
S1 <- matrix(c(1:8,9,1,1,1), nrow = 3, ncol = 4, byrow=TRUE)
```

> One can use this

```
cbind.data.frame(freq=frequency,s1=S1)
```

> Output

```
  freq s1.1 s1.2 s1.3 s1.4
1   CU    1    2    3    4
2   XU    5    6    7    8
3   UK    9    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

A matrix only accepts one type of data, in your case transforming numeric to character. I recomend you to use the data structure of a data frame, the indexing is the same as a matrix. Try:

```
result = cbind(frequency, as.dataframe(S1))
```